# printing elements of a vector<Point2i>

Tags: c++, opencv, vector

If I have a vector and I initialize it like this. How do I access just the first part of the point separately and second separately.

```
vector<Point2i> cent_i(1); // how do i initialize with a point like (1,2 )
cent_i[0][0] = (floor( s.width/2)); //TRYING TO change the points
cent_i[0][1] = (floor( s.height/2));
```

I don't know if I am doing this right

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can initialize the point directly in the constructor, like:

```
vector<Point> pts {Point(1,2), Point(3,4), Point(5,6)};
```

or:

```
vector<Point> pts {{1,2}, {3,4}, {5,6}};
```

You can access i-th `Point` of the vector like:

```
pts[i].x = ...
pts[i].y = ...
```

Remember that `Point` is just a `typedef` for `Point2i`.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [**Documentation**](http://answers.opencv.org/question/17088/accessing-pointint-point2i-data-from-memory/) from OpenCv. Here is how you index a `std::vector` of `Point2i` named `points`:

```
points[0].x, points[0].y, points[1].x, points[1].y, ...
```